# Symfony2 change default validator messages

Tags: symfony, message, validation, constraints

Is there a way to change the default messages of base constraints (NotBlank, MinLength, etc.) **without** translation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is done via the translator.